# Pandas: Reindex always get the same results

Tags: pandas, tensorflow-datasets

The code is:

```
from IPython import display
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

california_housing_dataframe = pd.read_csv("https://dl.google.com/mlcc/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv", sep=",")

california_housing_dataframe = california_housing_dataframe.reindex(
    np.random.permutation(california_housing_dataframe.index))


training_examples = california_housing_dataframe.head(12000)
validation_examples = california_housing_dataframe.tail(5000)

print("Training examples summary:")
display.display(training_examples.describe())
print("Validation examples summary:")
display.display(validation_examples.describe())
```

the result is:

```
Training examples summary:
          longitude         ...          median_house_value
count  12000.000000         ...                12000.000000
mean    -118.470274         ...               198037.593083
std        1.243589         ...               111857.499335
min     -121.390000         ...                14999.000000
25%     -118.940000         ...               117100.000000
50%     -118.210000         ...               170500.000000
75%     -117.790000         ...               244400.000000
max     -114.310000         ...               500001.000000

[8 rows x 9 columns]
Validation examples summary:
         longitude         ...          median_house_value
count  5000.000000         ...                 5000.000000
mean   -122.182510         ...               229532.878600
std       0.480337         ...               122520.063454
min    -124.350000         ...                14999.000000
25%    -122.400000         ...               130400.000000
50%    -122.140000         ...               213000.000000
75%    -121.910000         ...               303150.000000
max    -121.390000         ...               500001.000000
```

What confused me is that I got the same results every time,  but it would get different results runnig at: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/feature_sets.ipynb

Are there something wrong with my code or enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the same random seed every time you're run it. Try setting the numpy random seed to something different at the start of your script:

```
np.random.seed(42)
```

Try changing the seed value, and see if it changes the randomization. If that is the case then the following "hack" should work to give you random outputs every run:

```
import datetime
random_enough_seed = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()*1000)
np.random.seed(random_enough_seed)
```

Comment: But won't that fix the ordering again, since the RNG is seeded the same way each time?

Comment: Yes, but if it does affect your output, you know that it has to do with the seed, and you can figure out a way to mitigate the problem.

Comment: Okay... so just to clarify, this is a debugging suggestion, not an actual answer, right?

Comment: display.display(california_housing_dataframe .describe()) is ok, display.display(training_examples.describe()) always the same.

Comment: Now it is a full answer, not just a debugging. If it turns out it has nothing to do with the seed, I'll delete it.

Comment: @VicWei I get different results: Train mean long first run = -119.569948 vs second run = -119.559058, test mean long first run =-119.543292 vs second run = -119.569430.

Comment: I tried,  it migtht have nothing to do with the seed. I still get the same result.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen but mime are always 118.470274, I think it has something to do with my environment.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen It should be about -119.6 both training_examples and validation_examples. But mime are -118.470274 and -122.182510. I will try to run at a different machine.

Comment: @VicWei Did you try with different seeds between runs? `np.random.seed(42)` vs `np.random.seed(62)` for example?

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen Yes, I tried with different seeds, but no effect.

Comment: @VicWei Did you make sure to set the seed before the `np.random.permutation()` function call?

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen yes, I am sure. Actually california_housing_dataframe.reindex(
    np.random.permutation(california_housing_dataframe.index))
 works, wih or without np.random.seed(). The index changed when I inspect the data.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen No,  but I got the right results in another machine.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I changed the randomize code to:

```
california_housing_dataframe = california_housing_dataframe.reindex(
    np.random.permutation(list(california_housing_dataframe.index)))
```

but I don't know why.